# MySQL | Request from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, request

**I have a tables:**

```
1. orders

id userid status placed
1  1      9      2014-05-02
2  1      8      2014-05-02 

2. products

id qty name
1  1   Samsung galaxy s4
2  1   Samsung galaxy s4

3. orders_products

id orderid productid qty
1  1       1         2 
2  2       2         2
```

My request looks like below:

```
SELECT P.name, SUM(OP.qty) count FROM `orders_products` OP, `products` P WHERE OP.productid = P.id GROUP BY P.id ORDER BY SUM(OP.qty) DESC LIMIT 10
```

How can I show results where order status = 9 for example and placed between two dates?

Thanks!

Comment: Add that condition to the query?

Comment: o.status = 9 ... also, don't use implicit (comma-) join syntax. Use explicit JOIN syntax instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this , its another variation of what you are trying to achieve.

```
select
p.id,
p.name,
coalesce (sum(`tot`),0) as `count`
from products p
inner join
(
  select 
  sum(qty) as `tot`,
  productid
  from orders_products
  inner join `orders` on `orders`.`id` = orders_products.orderid
  where `orders`.status = 9
  group by productid
)t
on p.id = t.productid
group by p.id
order by `count`
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9bda3/4)

Comment: Thanks for solution. Is it possible to achieve this simpler?

Comment: well its simple, think this way.. get the count by joining orders and order_products with the condition then join the result with product to get the the final result by the joining key idproduct.

Comment: Ok. Understand. How can I add something like that AND `placed` BETWEEN "'.$date1.'" AND "'.$date2.'"' ?

Comment: you can add `AND o.placed between "'.$date1.'" AND "'.$date2.'"'`